# Why my simple java client/server sample program that uses "readAllBytes" method hang?

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

I was learning java socket programming, and wrote a pair of very simple server and client classes.  The server listens on port 12345, receives the message from the client, and sends the message back to the client.  The client sends a message, and receives response from server. However, when I started the sever class first, and then started the client class, both processes hang. Any insights on where I did wrong?  Thank you!

I am using openjdk 15.0.1

```
java -version
openjdk version "15.0.1" 2020-10-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 15.0.1+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 15.0.1+9, mixed mode, sharing)
```

The classes are as below:

Server class:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class SimpleServer {
    private static final int SERVER_PORT = 12345;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVER_PORT);
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
        InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
        String input = new String(in.readAllBytes());
        OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
        os.write(input.getBytes());
        os.flush();
        os.close();
    }
 }
```

The client class:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class SimpleClient {
    public static final int SERVER_PORT = 12345;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", SERVER_PORT);
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        writer.println("GET /resources HTTP/1.1");
        writer.flush();
        InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
        String result = new String(is.readAllBytes());
        System.out.println("response : " + result);
        writer.close();
        is.close();
        socket.close();
    }
 }
```

Comment: @ScaryWombat  i removed the "package com.sample" lines in the post. can you try again to see if you still have problems with compilation?  thank you!

Comment: My bad, still using jdk8

Comment: regarding your code I am *guessing* that the server is closing the socket before the client has read it.  Usually the server would be in a loop, so that it can accept many times

Comment: In you client remove `throws Exception` and catch it in the program.  It may tell you that the socket is already closed.

Comment: As you suggested earlier, the problem is with using "readAllBytes" method.  The reallAllBytes() method can't automatically close the InputStream instance. When it can reach the end of a stream, the further invocations of this method can return an empty byte array.  The problem is that  socket inputstream does not have an end of stream token until the socket is closed. That is the reason that both programs hang without progress...

Comment: You should make an answer with your findings.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with using "readAllBytes" method. The reallAllBytes() method is introduced in Java 9. It can't automatically close the InputStream instance. When it can reach the end of a stream, the further invocations of this method can return an empty byte array. The problem is that socket inputstream does not have an end of stream token until the socket is closed. That is the reason that both programs hang without progress.  The updated client program is as below. The change in server program is similar.

```
public class SimpleClient {
    public static final int SERVER_PORT = 12345;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", SERVER_PORT);
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        writer.println("GET /resources HTTP/1.1");
        writer.flush();

        InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        is.read(buffer);

        String result = new String(buffer);
        System.out.println("response : " + result);
        writer.close();
        is.close();
       socket.close();
    }
}
```